# Windows 10 x64 StorNVMe Flooding DebugView?

Tags: windows-10, debug, nvme

All of a sudden I'm getting flooded in DebugView with a loop of this information:

```
587615937500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Setting F-state idle timeout to 200ms
587617968750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: F-State Idle Timer Expired, Setting Latency Tolerance to 15ms
587617968750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: F-State Callback for F2
587617968750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Transitioning to NVME PS4 - MaxP: 4000uW, Latency: 14000us
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: F-State Callback for F0
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Transitioning to NVME PS0 - MaxP: 4000000uW, Latency: 0us
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Setting F-state idle timeout to 200ms
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Setting F-state idle timeout to 200ms
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Setting F-state idle timeout to 200ms
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Setting F-state idle timeout to 200ms
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Setting F-state idle timeout to 200ms
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Setting F-state idle timeout to 200ms
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Setting F-state idle timeout to 200ms
587622187500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
587622343750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
587622343750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Setting F-state idle timeout to 200ms
587622343750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
587622343750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
587622343750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Setting F-state idle timeout to 200ms
587622343750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
587622343750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
587622343750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: Setting F-state idle timeout to 200ms
587622343750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
587622343750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
```

Is this due to one of the Windows updates?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's the root cause of this. But as a workaround, I just used a filter in Exclude "STORMINI*" and it fixed the issue temporarily.

[image: Filter Button]

---

[image: Exclude Filter]